# passing values from a class to another callable class

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I have a class with the below code,

```
public class DocTransformer implements Callable<IndexableDocument> {

    WDoc document;
    public DocTransformer(Map<INDEXFIELD, Tokenizer> tknizerMap, WDoc doc) {
        this.document = doc;
    }

    public IndexableDocument call() throws TokenizerException {
        System.out.println("Inside doctrans: "+this.document.getId());

    }

}
```

the IndexableDocument looks like below,

```
public class IndexableDocument {

    WDoc doc;
    public IndexableDocument() {
        System.out.println("this is inside indexable document");
    }

    public void addField(INDEXFIELD field, TStream stream) {
        //TODO: Implement this method
    }

    public TokenStream getStream(INDEXFIELD key) {
        //TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }

    public String getDocumentIdentifier() {
        System.out.println(doc.getId);
    }

}
```

A runner class calls the DocTransformer. I can access WDoc inside the DocTransformer as it is being called from the runner class and the object is passed from it to DocTransformer. But I need to access the WDoc object inside IndexableDocument. How to achieve it? Please explain if my question needs to rephrased, as I am very new to threads.

Comment: Can't you just add a getter for the `WDoc doc` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter and Setter for this WDOC use [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) for it, and don't forget make WDOC final.

```
Exchanger<WDoc> exchanger = new Exchanger<WDoc>(); \\do it inside some Cover Thread(mb your main class)
currentWdoc = exchanger.exchange(doc); \\ inside getter
```

if you nedd WDOC only for read . you can just Use getter and final field